# Kafka Java Consumer hangs on Jenkins and does not read message on local

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I created consumer using below dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the code for consumer:

```
    private static String TopicName = "Automation_kafka_test";
    LOGGER.info("Initializing the consumer");
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> myKafkaCascadeConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(KafkaCascadeConsumer.kafkaCascadeConfiguration());
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : KafkaCascadeConsumer.kafkaCascadeConfiguration().entrySet()) 
    {
     LOGGER.info("Key = "+entry.getKey() + ", Value =" + entry.getValue());
    }

 KafkaConsumerHelper.readKafkaMessages(myKafkaCascadeConsumer, TopicName);
        myKafkaCascadeConsumer.close();


// read Kafka messages
        public static void readKafkaMessages(KafkaConsumer<String, String> myKafkaConsumer, String topicName) {
            LOGGER.info("Subscribing to Topic =" + topicName);
            myKafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
                 while (true) {
                     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = myKafkaConsumer.poll(100);
                     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                         System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
                 }

        }
```

Below is the output:

```
2018-05-30 14:23:21,247  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:81) - Initializing the consumer
2018-05-30 14:23:21,869  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:87) - Key = key.deserializer, Value =org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
2018-05-30 14:23:21,869  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:87) - Key = value.deserializer, Value =org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
2018-05-30 14:23:21,869  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:87) - Key = enable.auto.commit, Value =false
2018-05-30 14:23:21,869  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:87) - Key = group.id, Value =AutomationRamtest1
2018-05-30 14:23:21,870  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:87) - Key = consumer.timeout.ms, Value =50000
2018-05-30 14:23:21,871  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:87) - Key = bootstrap.servers, Value =ABsrd00xxx:9092,ABsrd00yyy:9092 ***** masked for privacy***
2018-05-30 14:23:21,871  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:87) - Key = auto.commit.interval.ms, Value =1000
2018-05-30 14:23:21,871  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (US000000_KafkaTest.java:87) - Key = auto.offset.reset, Value =earliest
2018-05-30 14:23:21,887  INFO [TestNG-test=Test-1] (KafkaConsumerHelper.java:53) - Subscribing to Topic =Automation_kafka_test
```

Jenkins stucks at above statement, and never get out of it. Also this code never get any message back on my local but when using CLI, developer gets message back from same topic I am reading.

Also I use same bootstrap.servers setting for  producer and it works.

Can you please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Does the `group.id` stay the same every time the test runs? After the consumer group identified by the group.id consumes all the messages in the topic, subsequent test runs will not find any messages in the topic, unless a producer sent more messages to the topic.

Comment: Thanks for checking it. Yes, I generate new message each time through producer so that consumer would have some messages to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was with group assignment. If there is only single partition and if any past consumer is not terminated properly then Kafka wait for maximum long value to terminate it. In between if you try to add consumer in same group then it will not read.

Below article explains relationship between group, partition and topic.

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html